# How do I specify where to save the debug.log?

Tags: plugin-development, debug, wp-debug

According to the documentation cited below I should be able to add a path to save the debug.log at but it does not seem to be working for me.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/tmp/wp-errors.log' );
```

in wp-config.php I have:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/tmp/wp-errors.log' );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

The log keeps saving to the default location instead. Any help as too why this would not behave as expected is appreciated.

Running WP Version 5.0.8
With WordFence installed

Comment: What is the default location? Have you confirmed that location is actually writable? If you have access to `/tmp`  is there a reason you don't just use the normal PHP error log?

Comment: The default save location as specified in the documentation is wp-content/debug.log and it keeps saving there even when specifying other locations. the /tmp/wp-error.log used above is the sample given in the doc. I have also tried /wp-content/custom-path/debug.log with no success including WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/custom-path/debug.log' in case it need the full path. So those location should be writable even if tmp was not.